# Keyboard mapping stops working -- how to debug?

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-layout, debugging

I am alternating between two layouts, English and Hungarian (the latter has some accented characters).

The problem is that sometimes **the Hungarian layout stops working**, i.e. when I switch to it, the indicator shows `hu`, but still when typing, I get the characters corresponding to the English layout, instead of the Hungarian ones. (Or sometimes even when the layout has been switched to `hu` for a while, I get back the English characters.)

Restarting the window-manager (Alt-F2 + `r`) solves the problem, but it is annoying and ideally I would like to fix it, and most importantly **understand** what the issue is.

So the question is: **where to start debugging**? Which logs/settings should I look at, to find some possible error message which could lead me one step further?

In case it matters: Ubuntu 20.04 with Gnome (any other necessary details?)

**Updates as per comments:**

- I believe all applications are affected (I typically use terminal and Firefox, those two are definitely affected, but will try some other, when the issue happens again)
  Update: 2022.05.08: Confirmed, seems that **all** apps are affected (tried Firefox, Terminal, Libreoffice, Text editor)
- `LC_` environment variables are the same in both cases:

```
# when mapping is broken
$ env | grep LC_
LC_ADDRESS=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_NAME=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_MONETARY=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_PAPER=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC=en_GB.UTF-8


# when mapping is ok
$ env | grep LC_
LC_ADDRESS=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_NAME=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_MONETARY=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_PAPER=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC=en_GB.UTF-8
```

Comment: "When typing, I get characters…" : When typing under what application ? some xterm ? text editor ? libreoffice ? some browser ? Any one of them ? Additionally, could you please post the output of env | grep LC_ when things are according to your desire and the same when things are no longer according to your desire. (v.g before restarting your dm and immediately after having restarted it)

Comment: @MC68020: updated the question with the details. For my understanding: are the LC-variables supposed to change when I switch the layout?

Comment: No they are not. However if any setting went inadvertantly changed, that could have explained why restarting the dm fixes the problem. But, this is apparently not the case.